# How to use gulp-newer?

Tags: gulp, gulp-newer

I'm new to gulp and I tried to follow the documentation in https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer to understand how it works. However its not working as expected for the below task. I think I'm missing something obvious.

Here's the folder structure,

```
    temp
      file1.js
      file2.js
    new
      file1.js
      file3.js
    change
      <empty initially>
```

I want to compare *temp* folder with *new* folder and if there are any new files in *new* folder(which was not present in temp earlier) then move those files to change folder. This is just me trying to understand how gulp-newer works. Am I doing it right?

```
    gulp.task('newer', function() {
        return gulp.src('temp/*.js')
                .pipe(newer('new/*.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('change')) 
        });
```

However when I run this task it just copy all the files in *temp* folder to *change* folder. So after task run *change* folder has file1.js and file2.js. I'm expecting just file3.js to be present in change(since that's a new file). Correct me if my understanding with the approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

From [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer):

> Using newer with many:1 source:dest mappings Plugins like gulp-concat
>   take many source files and generate a single destination file. In this
>   case, the newer stream will pass through all source files if any one
>   of them is newer than the destination file. The newer plugin is
>   configured with the destination file path.

and the sample code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

// Concatenate all if any are newer 
gulp.task('concat', function() {

  // Add the newer pipe to pass through all sources if any are newer 
  return gulp.src('lib/*.js')
      .pipe(newer('dist/all.js'))
      .pipe(concat('all.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});
```

it seems that you need to pass in all the files already concatenated to newer. In your case:

```
gulp.task('newer', function() {
        return gulp.src('temp/*.js')
                .pipe(newer('new/*.js'))
                .pipe(concat('*.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('change')) 
        });
```

Also, since newer checks the files modified date make sure that the files are actually newer. I know it's obvious, but I'm usually stuck on "obvious" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

May I also suggest [gulp-newy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newy) in which you can manipulate the path and  filename in your own function. Then, just use the function as the callback to the `newy()`. This gives you complete control of the files you would like to compare.

This will allow 1:1 or many to 1 compares.

```
newy(function(projectDir, srcFile, absSrcFile) {
  // do whatever you want to here. 
  // construct your absolute path, change filename suffix, etc. 
  // then return /foo/bar/filename.suffix as the file to compare against
}
```

[image]